Java Spring boot: : Not a managed type error (very new to spring)
I am extremely new to Spring and still learning core concepts, so I will be very grateful and appreciate if I get detailed answer. Basically I'm creating a webapp serving somewhat like a REST catalog of employees stored in embedded database.
I'm trying to implement endpoints serving employees as JSON representations of classes.
First I'm trying to implement endpoint /employees which lists all employees.
I get an error: Not a managed type: class springemployeecatalog.domain.Employee
Please not: It is required from me to absolutely not use any annotations at the start of domain classes (like @entity)
As I understood processes in this application should be the following:

A request comes in from the client.
The controller handles the request and retrieves data from the service layer.
The service layer fetches the data from the database using a repository. The data is retrieved as domain objects.
The service layer then converts the domain objects into DTOs. This is done using a mapper.
The DTOs are sent back to the controller.
The controller sends the DTOs to the client as the response.

Please correct me on above points if I'm wrong. This is the code I wrote:
Employee.java:
public class Employee {
    private final Long id;
    private final FullName fullName;
    private final Position position;
    private final LocalDate hired;
    private final BigDecimal salary;
    private final Employee manager;
    private final Department department;

    @JsonCreator
    public Employee(@JsonProperty("id") final Long id,
                    @JsonProperty("fullName") final FullName fullName,
                    @JsonProperty("position") final Position position,
                    @JsonProperty("hired") final LocalDate hired,
                    @JsonProperty("salary") final BigDecimal salary,
                    @JsonProperty("manager") final Employee manager,
                    @JsonProperty("department") final Department department) {
        this.id = id;
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.position = position;
        this.hired = hired;
        this.salary = salary.setScale(5, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        this.manager = manager;
        this.department = department;
    }
//getters

department.java:
public class Department {

    private final Long id;
    private final String name;
    private final String location;

    @JsonCreator
    public Department(@JsonProperty("id") final Long id,
                    @JsonProperty("name") final String name,
                    @JsonProperty("location") final String location) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.location = location;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }
//getters

EmployeeDTO.java:
public class EmployeeDTO {
    private Long id;
    private FullName fullName;
    private Position position;
    private LocalDate hireDate;
    private BigDecimal salary;
    private EmployeeDTO manager;
    private DepartmentDTO department;
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public FullName getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public Position getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public LocalDate getHired() {
        return hireDate;
    }

    public BigDecimal getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public EmployeeDTO getManager() {
        return manager;
    }

    public DepartmentDTO getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }
    public EmployeeDTO(Long id, FullName fullName, Position position, LocalDate hireDate, BigDecimal salary, EmployeeDTO manager, DepartmentDTO department) {
        this.id = id;
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.position = position;
        this.hireDate = hireDate;
        this.salary = salary;
        this.manager = manager;
        this.department = department;
    }

}

departmentdto.java:
public class DepartmentDTO {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String location;

    public DepartmentDTO(Long id, String name, String location) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.location = location;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }
}

employeerepository.java:
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {
}

departmentrepository.java:
@Repository
public interface DepartmentRepository extends JpaRepository<Department, Long> {
}

employeeservice.java:
@Service
public class EmployeeService {
    private final EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;
    private final DepartmentRepository departmentRepository;

    @Autowired
    public EmployeeService(EmployeeRepository employeeRepository, DepartmentRepository departmentRepository) {
        this.employeeRepository = employeeRepository;
        this.departmentRepository = departmentRepository;
    }

    public List<EmployeeDTO> getAllEmployees() {
        return employeeRepository.findAll().stream()
                .map(this::convertToEmployeeDto)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public List<DepartmentDTO> getAllDepartments() {
        return departmentRepository.findAll().stream()
                .map(this::convertToDepartmentDto)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
    private EmployeeDTO convertToEmployeeDto(Employee employee) {
        Department department = employee.getDepartment();
        Employee manager = employee.getManager();
    
        return new EmployeeDTO(
                employee.getId(),
                employee.getFullName(),
                employee.getPosition(),
                employee.getHired(),
                employee.getSalary(),
                manager != null ? convertToEmployeeDto(manager) : null,
                department != null ? convertToDepartmentDto(department) : null
        );
    }

    private DepartmentDTO convertToDepartmentDto(Department department) {
        return new DepartmentDTO(
                department.getId(),
                department.getName(),
                department.getLocation()
        );
    }
}

emloyeecontroller.java:
@RestController
public class EmployeeController {
    private final EmployeeService employeeDepartmentService;

    @Autowired
    public EmployeeController(EmployeeService employeeDepartmentService) {
        this.employeeDepartmentService = employeeDepartmentService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/employees")
    public List<EmployeeDTO> getAllEmployees() {
        return employeeDepartmentService.getAllEmployees();
    }
}

database schema:
CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENT
(
    ID       INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    NAME     VARCHAR(14),
    LOCATION VARCHAR(13)
);

CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE
(
    ID         INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    FIRSTNAME  VARCHAR(10),
    LASTNAME   VARCHAR(10),
    MIDDLENAME VARCHAR(10),
    POSITION   VARCHAR(9),
    MANAGER    INTEGER,
    HIREDATE   DATE,
    SALARY     DOUBLE,
    DEPARTMENT INTEGER,
    CONSTRAINT FK_DEPTNO FOREIGN KEY (DEPARTMENT) REFERENCES DEPARTMENT (ID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_EMPNO FOREIGN KEY (MANAGER) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE (ID)
);

COMMIT;

Please tell me if I need to provide additional code.
I understand that my code could cause you frustration. I am sorry in advance. I am trying my best to get familiar with this framework, since I have never touched it until now.

If you can't use annotations you may use xml descriptor.

It is a right intuition and a good practice to not use spring annotations on domain classes. You should keep using Employee in your domain, but once you reach EmployeeRepository it requires you to pass an @Entity annotated class. So the preferred way would be to map your Employee domain object into an Entity, called for example EmployeeEntity and use this type within your EmployeeRepository.
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<EmployeeEntity, Long> {
}

Since you are also referring to Department in Employee, the EmployeeEntity should be referring to DepartmentEntity. Remaining fields with value object types, such as FullName should be mapped to something that Spring JPA will understand. In this case it would be a String.
With that out the way you can then look at Spring boot - Not a managed type where a fellow user encountered similar error which would be solved by adding more required annotations.
Good luck with learning Spring.

Why downvote? Answer is correct. Not a managed type is issue about entities managing. And this is fixing by adding @Entity annotation. In some cases we also need to add @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages={})
